# Printing from a PC to a Mac prints out too light

Tags: windows, macos, printer

I have my two Windows PCs hooked up to a printer that is connected to an iMac.  When printing from the iMac the printout is fine but when printing **from the PC the print out is too light**.  Any ideas?

Comment: This maybe be a Driver issue... Can you provide your brand/model of your printer?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that your printer settings on the PC are not set to "economy" mode.